# Extracting zip file in memory failing with C# DotNetZip

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

I'm trying to download and extract a zip file in C#, specifically DotNetZip.

When I run this code...

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(reportUrl);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        stream.CopyTo(ms);
        ms.Seek(0, 0);
        ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(ms);
        zip.Seek(0, 0);

        ZipEntry e = zip.GetNextEntry();
        string s = e.FileName;

        MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
        e.Extract(ms2);
```

After the Extract method executes, I get...

```
        $exception  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

[image: Here's what the object looks like before the method runs]

Comment: My immediate thought is that InputStream is null

Comment: you tried using a different memorystream instance?

Comment: What do you mean "after the Extract method executes"? Does it execute properly before throwing the exception? What is the next line of code after Extract?

Comment: Okay, I was wondering about InputStream being null too, but I can't figure out anything wrong with my construction of the ZipInputStream that would cause that. And I'm not sure if it's supposed to be anything, because my impression is that a ZipEntry has already had its data copied out of the stream that created it.

Comment: @Ethan, it is the end of the function. Sorry for not being clear, the Extract method throws the exception.

Comment: @Mike, hmmm...what do you mean by using a different instance of memorystream? I'm new to C#, but I initialize it, copy to it, and then use it right there.

Comment: Are you trying to extract from or to the memorystream?

Comment: My thoughts are that by how you are using the library that you are reading/writing to the same stream.  Try MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();e.Extract(ms2);

Comment: OH thanks Mike. Good catch. I believe I was definitely doing that before and having problems, but I will try again for sure. Oops.

Comment: I'll post as an answer please do with it as you see fit after testing :D

Comment: Yes, same exception. :( I will update my question to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to say why your code doesn't work. I would start by simplifying it and ensuring that I am properly disposing all disposable resources such as streams:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var url = "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit3.8.1.zip";
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(client.DownloadData(url)))
        {
            foreach (var entry in zip)
            {
                entry.Extract(".");
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you checkout the documentation for [many useful examples](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/Examples.htm) of using the DotNetZip library.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer Darin! However, that doesn't compile for me (.NET 4.0, latest version of DotNetZip). I don't want to butcher your answer by relying on my non-existent C# to make it work... what would be the best way to go from Byte.Array (DownloadData return value) to IO.Stream, which is required by the Read command??

Comment: @Charles Offenbacher, what error are you getting? Because I've just tested this code on my Win7 x64 VS2010 .NET 4.0 and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: ZipFile.Read seems to only take a filename string or Stream for me...weird I'm on VS2010 .NET 4.0 Win7 x64 too....hmmm... 1 sec.

Comment: @Charles Offenbacher, there are many overloads of the `ZipFile.Read`. For convenience, in my example, I use the one that takes a byte array, because that's what happens to be returned from the `client.DownloadData` method.

Comment: Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Comment: @Charles Offenbacher, did you download the latest version of DotNetZip? I used NuGet to fetch it. I have 19 overloads of the `ZipFile.Read` static method :-)

Comment: Haha :) I believe that there are many overloads, they're just not working for me. Let me try rolling back to the other version of DotNetZip... I am on Alpha... although I'd be surprised if they changed that.

Comment: @Charles Offenbacher, that's what I did: create a new Console Application in VS2010, install the DotNetZip NuGet package (happens to be v 1.9), put the code I've shown in `Program.cs` and rock and roll.

Comment: Wow! Beautiful! NuGet solved that problem. I think it downgraded me, but your code compiles now. Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure everything is working now. Still have no idea about the ZipInputStream stuff, but my impression is that ZipFile is much older and more robust, so this is a great solution. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I'm seeing the same error that Charles did and I just installed DotNetZip via nuget.  For some reason, I only see 4 overloads and they all want a stream as an input.