# Cannot create DotNetZip ZipFile from file download via HTTP Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, memorystream, dotnetzip

I am try to download a zip file via a url to extract files from.  I would rather not have to save it a temp file (which works fine) and rather keep it in memory - it is not very big.  For example, if I try to download this file:

http://phs.googlecode.com/files/Download%20File%20Test.zip

using this code:

```
using Ionic.Zip;
...
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.ContentLength > 0)
{
    using (MemoryStream zipms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int bytesRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];

        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                zipms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(stream); // <--ERROR: "This stream does not support seek operations. "
        }

        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipms)) // <--ERROR: "Could not read block - no data!  (position 0x00000000) "
        using (MemoryStream txtms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ZipEntry csentry= zip["Download File Test.cs"];
            csentry.Extract(txtms);
            txtms.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(txtms))
            {
                string csentry = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Note where i flagged the errors I am receiving.  With the first one, it does not like the System.Net.ConnectStream.  If I comment that line out and allow it to hit the line where I note the second error, it does not like the MemoryStream.  I did see this posting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377099/1324284 but I am having the same issues that others mention about not having more then 4 overloads of the Read method so I cannot try the WebClient.

However, if I do everything via a FileStream and save it to a temp location first, then point ZipFile.Read at that temp location, everything works including extracting any contained files into a MemoryStream.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `Flush()` your `MemoryStream` and set the `Position` to 0 before you read from it, otherwise you are trying to read from the current position (where there is nothing).

For your code:

```
ZipFile zip;
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        zipms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    zipms.Flush();
    zipms.Position = 0;
    zip = ZipFile.Read(zipms);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Halvard.  Sorry if I wasnt clearer, I put both lines with the errors in there to save space.  If I commment out the first one with the error it will proceed until it gets to the next line with the error.  I did try the Position reset before but it gives an error of "This stream does not support seek operations." I tried flushing as you suggested but it made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: @Ernie It is possible I am missing your point, but could you try the code above (I have just edited it to make clear what I am trying to accomplish)?  What error do you get when you only run this code?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  If I put your above code, an error occurs at zipms.Position = 0 saying it does not support the seek.  If I remove the 2 lines you added plus the line with 'zip=...' below them, the code will continue just fine.  It will then error on 'using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipms))' I reference in the original posting.  Hope the clears it up.

Comment: @Ernie  That is strange.  I created a simple test project that does not crash when setting `zipms.Position = 0;`.  Oh, well, sorry I could not help.  Good luck finding an answer!  (and please post if you do)

Comment: Thanks for trying.  What version of DotNetZip are you running?  Did you just download it from their website?

Comment: @Ernie I did not use DotNetZip, so I didn't know if `zip = ZipFile.Read(zipms)` would work, but I used the memory stream for something else and had no problem reading it.  That is why I am surprised that the error comes at `zipms.Position = 0;`, which works fine for me, instead of `zip = ZipFile.Read(zipms);`  Otherwise my code was identical to yours (except I used a different URL).